# Entering fields for songs database in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I'm very new to Access. What I'm trying to do is create a database for songs which I will use to automatically create PowerPoint slides.

Most of the songs will be in Chinese, and the database will contain fields such as song name, number of characters in song name, number of strokes of first character of song name, verse 1 lyrics, verse 2 lyrics, chorus 1 lyrics, chorus 2 lyrics, etc.

I have an Excel file with the first column containing single characters and the second column containing the number of strokes of the character. I've imported this into Access as a table.

How do I get Access to automatically fill in the "number of characters in song name" and "number of strokes of first character of song name" fields for a record once I fill in the "song name" field?

I would prefer editing the database directly without using forms.

Comment: You can cslculate these values in the queries, you do not need to store them in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Query then use a Calculated Field.

You can use [LEN](http://599cd.com/glossary/access/len/) to get the Length of Field.

You could use the [SPLIT](http://599cd.com/glossary/access/split/) function to split your song name on spaces then get the len of the first item.